# how to locate multiple places in Map (IOS)

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I want to get display top 10 cricket Grounds in map.

In my Code I got only one location, which is simulators default longitude and latitude values.

How to display multiple locations?

.h

```
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>


@interface ViewController : UIViewController<CLLocationManagerDelegate>

{

CLLocationManager *locationManager;


CLLocation *currentLocation;

    IBOutlet UILabel *label1;
    IBOutlet UILabel *lable2;

}


@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *myMapview;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label2;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lable1;
@end
```

.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad

{

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];



    locationManager.delegate = self;


    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;


    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;


    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];


    _myMapview.showsUserLocation = YES;

    [self->locationManager startUpdatingLocation];



    CLLocation *location = [locationManager location];


    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = [location coordinate];


    NSString *latitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", coordinate.latitude];
    NSString *longitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", coordinate.longitude];

    //NSLog(@”dLatitude : %@”, latitude);
    //NSLog(@”dLongitude : %@”,longitude);
    NSLog(@"MY HOME :%@", latitude);
    NSLog(@"MY HOME: %@ ", longitude);

}

#pragma mark CLLocationManager Delegate
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    currentLocation = [locations objectAtIndex:0];
    [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];

    [self->locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];




    NSLog(@"my latitude :%f",currentLocation.coordinate.latitude);

    NSLog(@"my longitude :%f",currentLocation.coordinate.longitude);
    label1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.longitude];
    lable2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude];


    NSLog(@"Detected Location : %f, %f", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude, currentLocation.coordinate.longitude);
    CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init] ;
    [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:currentLocation
                   completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error)
     {
                       if (error)
                       {
                           NSLog(@"Geocode failed with error: %@", error);
                           return;
                       }

NSLog(@"Monday");
                       CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
                       NSLog(@"placemark.ISOcountryCode %@",placemark.ISOcountryCode);

                   }];
}
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    NSLog(@"didUpdateToLocation: %@", newLocation);
    CLLocation *currentLocation = newLocation;

    if (currentLocation != nil)
    {

    label1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.longitude];
    lable2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude];
    }
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check below link.

http://jprithvi.wordpress.com/tag/display-multiple-pins-in-ios-map/

I hope this is what you are looking for.

Few more links.

http://jonathanfield.me/mkmapview-adding-pins-map-showing-annotations/

http://mayurbirari.wordpress.com/2011/02/07/how-to-access-mkmapkit-in-iphone/

http://sugartin.info/2011/07/01/map-view-controller-with-multiple-pin-on-google-map/

Answer (score 0):

You'll able to display the user location by the classic user annotation on the map.

If you want to change your location in simulator, just add gpx files to your projet.
Then you will be able to switch between locations by this way : in xcode > debug > simulate locations

To add other locations on your map, you just have to add annotations (MKAnnontations)